# get_absolute_url don't work in Django

Tags: django

Model:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('cars.views.car', args=[str(self.id)])
```

View:

```
def car(request):
    all_cars = Car.objects.all().filter(active=1).values('id', 'name')
    return render(request, 'car.html', {'all_cars': all_cars})
```

URL mapping:

```
url(r'^car/$', 'cars.views.car'),
```

in `car.html`, I'm using:

```
<li><a href="{{ car.get_absolute_url }}">{{ car.name }}</a></li>
```

But it didn't print /car/N/, only /car/. How to fix it? With [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#get-absolute-url) (`<!-- BAD template code. Avoid! -->`) it works, but dont works with `get_absolute_url`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your URL pattern doesn't accept any argument, so django can't generate an URL with the argument!

```
url(r'^car/$', 'cars.views.car'), # Where would django add the parameter?!
```

Should be:

```
url(r'^car/(?P<car_id>\d+)/$', 'cars.views.car'),
```

But then your `car` view wouldn't work, because it looks like it gives a listing of cars.

You probably want two URLS: one for a car listing, and one for a specific car. They'll need to map to two different views:

```
url(r'^car/$', 'cars.views.list_cars'), # List of all cars.
url(r'^car/(?P<car_id>\d+)/$', 'cars.views.view_car'), # View a specific car, map get_aboluste_url to this view.
```

---

On a sidenote, you should look into [generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/), they would make this entire process simpler.

Comment: Personally I think using generic views is like hurting your own foot using a hammer :)

Comment: @AamirAdnan Well, what can I say?

Comment: so, what code (get_absolute_url(self)) will be for your example?

Comment: @tim `return reverse('cars.views.view_var', args=[self.id])`. Using [named URL patterns](http://cookingupawebsiteindjango.blogspot.fr/2009/04/name-your-urls.html) would simplify the process a bit more!

Answer (score 0):

You can have a single url which can full fill both of your requirements but it depends on the structure of your template (how you are extending child templates). Lets make it work:

```
url(r'^car/(?:(?P<car_id>\d+)/)?$', 'cars.views.car', name="car_url"),
# you notice i have make car_id optional
```

Now your view should be:

```
def car(request, car_id=None):
    if car_id:
        # just get a single car
        all_cars = Car.objects.filter(active=1, pk=car_id).values('id', 'name')
    else:
        # get all cars
        all_cars = Car.objects.filter(active=1).values('id', 'name')
    return render(request, 'car.html', {'all_cars': all_cars})
```

In template use a [url tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#url) for url resolution:

```
<li><a href="{% url car_url car_id=car.id %}">{{ car.name }}</a></li>
```

For listing url just don't pass `car_id`:

```
<li><a href="{% url car_url %}">Browse Cars</a></li>
```